# How to increase content size of unordered list CSS

Tags: css, html-lists

I am trying to replace html unordered-list's content size.

I am able to did that using following code

```
ul {
  list-style: none; 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li { 
  padding-left: 16px; 
}

li::before {
  content: "•"; 
  padding-right: 8px;
  color: blue; 
}
```

But the content size of unordered list is small.

How can I increase the content size of unordered list.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the size of the custom "dot" become bigger, you can add
font-size at the li::before, since the content is text/font type

```
    li::before {
      content: "•"; 
      padding-right: 8px;
      color: blue;
      font-size: 100px 
    }
```